# A ruler with missing graduation.

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the minimum number of graduations, i.e. $f(n)$, on a ruler such that it can measure all integral units from $1$ to $n$, which $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, inclusively?

For example, to measure from $1$ to $5$ units, you only need $4$ graduations (not $6$) as shown in this figure:
[image]

So, how can we deduce a general way general way to find $f(x)$. I suspect this has something to do with combination, which is not something I'm familiar with. Can anyone give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to any ideas, hints, or questions if I've not made myself clear.

Comment: Rulers of this kind are related to _[Golomb rulers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler)_ after Solomon Golomb of USC who studied the problem extensively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These things have been studied, and the appropriate search terms for Googling are *sparse rulers*, *complete rulers*, *optimal rulers*, and *perfect rulers*, but as far as I know there is no known simple solution which works for all lengths $n$.

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_ruler) on Sparse Rulers gives many examples and a number of references where you can find out what has already done on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment, but seemingly don't have a privilege to post comments (shouldn't a user have first ability to post comments and then answers?)

Assuming that the graduations contain the two boundary points, a simple lower bound for $m=f(n)$ is around $\sqrt{2n}$ (the number of segments achieved with $m$ graduations is $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ and for $m\gtrapprox \sqrt{2n}$, $n$ is reached)